# C# SMO Creating External Tables

Tags: c#, sql, smo

I am looking at creating a copy of my current database structure (without the data) programmatically using C# SMO libraries. I have got the Schema, Tables, Stored Procedures and the External Resources moving across successfully, however I am hvaing difficulty doing so. I am looking at using the Table Object provided as such:

```
TableCollection tables = server.Databases[source].Tables;

foreach (Table table in tables)
{
    if (table.IsExternal)
    {
        Table newTable = new Table(ddatabase, table.Name, table.Schema);
        foreach (Column col in table.Columns)
        {
            Column newColumn = new Column(newTable, col.Name, col.DataType);
            newTable.Columns.Add(newColumn);
        }
        //newTable.IsExternal = table.IsExternal;

        newTable.Create();
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the isExternal to set it to true, it throws an error. Leaving the code commented out it will create the tables but not as external tables.

Any ideas/suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution, I just needed to add the following code in:

```
newTable.ExternalTableDistribution = table.ExternalTableDistribution;
newTable.DataSourceName = table.DataSourceName;
newTable.IsExternal = true;
```